# Creating objects using symfony2 CRUD

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.6

I get the following exception when creating an object using symfony2 CRUD:

```
[ReflectionException]                               
Class App\CoransBundle\Entity\Coran does not exist
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: Stackoverflow is an English board, please edit your question so it fits the sites standards.

Comment: I got this problem when creating an entity with crud Symfony2

"[ReflectionException]
Class App \ CoransBundle \ Entity \ Koran does not exist "

I not find a solution: /

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very precise on whats wrong isn't it?

I guess you have a typo in your namespace definition of your Coran class. It should look like this:

```
namespace App\CoransBundle\Entity;
```

Comment: namespace App\CoransBundle\Entity; it 's exist

Comment: error when i execute the application "  Controller "App\CoransBundle\Controller\DefaultController::eleveAction" for URI "/eleve" is not callable."